# AIX 7.x inetd and tcp wrappers using chsubserver

Tags: services, aix

Greetings all the guru's and those who have knowledge I am yet to gain and share.

Sometime ago I configured TCP Wrappers on my AIX 7.1 & 7.2 LPAR's and it works great once you get the nuances sorted.

Non-tcpd services are easily managed with chsubserver ( https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/c_commands/chsubserver.html ) and I have this automated and scripted.

Having moved to TCP Wrapper's means I am struggling to automate changes to /etc/inetd.conf using chsubserver with tcp wrappers. Editing by hand is easy and sed/awk/grep help as work-around for now but the correct way is to use chsubserver.

Any help in constructing the chsubserver command to add & remove TCPD services from /etc/inetd.conf would be appreciated.

Here is my current setup :

```
[root@nim]/root # oslevel -s
7200-04-01-1939
[root@nim]/root # lssrc -l -s inetd
Subsystem         Group            PID          Status 
 inetd            tcpip            20709662     active
Debug         Not active 
Signal        Purpose 
 SIGALRM      Establishes socket connections for failed services. 
 SIGHUP       Rereads the configuration database and reconfigures services. 
 SIGCHLD      Restarts the service in case the service ends abnormally. 
Service       Command                  Description              Status 
 check_mk     /usr/bin/check_mk_agent                           active
[root@nim]/root # cat /etc/inetd.conf
# service  socket  protocol  wait/  user    server    server program
#  name     type             nowait         program     arguments
#
## # ---------------------------
## # TCP Wrapper Configuration :
## # ---------------------------
check_mk  stream tcp nowait root        /usr/sbin/tcpd          check_mk_agent
#ftp    stream  tcp6    nowait  root    /usr/sbin/tcpd          ftpd -l -u027
#tftp   dgram   udp6    SRC     nobody  /usr/sbin/tcpd          tftpd -n
#bootps dgram   udp     wait    root    /usr/sbin/tcpd          bootpd /etc/bootptab
## # -------------------------------
## # Non-TCP Wrapper Configuration :
## # -------------------------------
#check_mk_agent  stream tcp nowait root /usr/bin/check_mk_agent
#ftp    stream  tcp6    nowait  root    /usr/sbin/ftpd          ftpd -l -u027
#tftp   dgram   udp6    SRC     nobody  /usr/sbin/tftpd         tftpd -n
#bootps dgram   udp     wait    root    /usr/sbin/bootpd        bootpd /etc/bootptab
[root@nim]/root #
```

Thank you greatly in advance for taking the time to help out this stumped admin
Michael

Answer (score 1):

After some playing around in a lab environment I got the command working :

```
/usr/sbin/chsubserver -a -r inetd -v check_mk -p tcp -t stream -w nowait -u monitor -g /usr/sbin/tcpd check_mk_agent
```

In order to work the binary must be in or sym-linked to /usr/sbin (eg /usr/sbin/check_mk_agent) and the required entry must pre-exist in /etc/services (eg: check_mk   6556 # Check MK Monitoring)

The chsubserver command HUPS inetd when run but I like making sure and refreshing the inetd service (refresh -s inetd)

I hope this saves a poor techy some time :)